# Push JSON Data into All Array of JSON (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, json, arraylist

Let say I have this JSON.

```
[{ "a" : "1" , "b" : "2"},{ "a" : "2" , "b" : "2"}, { "a" : "3" , "b" : "3"}]
```

I want this

```
[{ "a" : "1" , "b" : "1" , "c" : "asd"},{ "a" : "2" , "b" : "2", "c" : "asd"}, { "a" : "3" , "b" : "3" , "c" : "asd"}]
```

How to add that "c" on each array through javascript?
I have try using arr.push({ "c" : "asd"}) but the result is

```
[{ "a" : "1" , "b" : "2"},{ "a" : "2" , "b" : "2"}, { "a" : "3" , "b" : "3"},{"c" : "asd"}]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is that all you've tried? I recommend reviewing for loops and iteration.

Comment: Sounds like you want [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Array.map is overkill for adding properties to an array of objects - forEach is perfectly OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arr.push` simply appends to the end of the array. What you want to do is to add a new mapping to each element in the array.

Therefore, you will want to iterate over the array and add a mapping.

```
let objarr = [{ "a" : "1" , "b" : "2"},{ "a" : "2" , "b" : "2"}, { "a" : "3" , "b" : "3"}];

for (var i = 0; i < objarr.length; i += 1) {
    objarr[i]["c"] = "asd";
}
```

In the above example, we iterate over each object in the array, mapping `c` to `asd`. Note that if an existing `c` mapping exists, it will be overwritten with `asd`.

Instead of using a regular for loop, you could also use a for-each loop to achieve the same effect.

I hope this helps.

Comment: or more simply `objarr.forEach(o => o.c = 'asd');`

Comment: I would rather use `map()` than `forEach()` as it keeps the code immutable and (according to my opinion) cleaner.

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks. I think your code is more simple and I am using it.